# Function calculate results wrong answer

Tags: c

I'm doing an exercise and I stuck with my code. I hope you guys can help me fix it.

[image]

And here is my function `fen()`:

```
double fen(double x,double y, int n) { // You should complete this function
    // Write your statements here
    double sum=1,temp;
    int j=2,k=1;
    double a = (x*y*y) / 18;
    sum=1-a;
    for(int i=2;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(;j<=i;j++)
        {
            a *= (x*y);
            for(;k<=(i+j);k++)
                    a /= k;
        }
        temp = a/(k*k);
        temp = (i%2 == 0) ? temp : -temp;
        sum+=temp;
    }

    return sum; //This statement must be changed 
 }
```

I've checked many times but still don't know why its result's wrong.
I've debugged and when `i=3`, a actually equal to `0.025` but it displayed`0.02499999999`.

Comment: maybe think about the accuracy from double

Comment: yep, I also think about it, but i still have no idea to get right output.
Test case sum = 0.1628 but my sum = 0.0090:((

Comment: What is your input (x, y, n)?

Comment: Considering the question, `Q2.cpp`, this is C++, not C.

Comment: Remember, all numbers are represented internally using **bits**, i.e. base 2.  Thus, `0.02499999999` may be the most precise the program can get to your desired result of `0.025` (which is 1/40).

Comment: If this problem is, in fact, due to `double` precision, then you should use a rounding function, e.g. `round()`, to get the correct answer.

Comment: I forgot :((. input is: x=2,y=3,n=1000.

Comment: If the answer is incorrect by more than just the rounding, I would start by removing all optimization and calculating the full `(x**n * y**(n+1)) / ((2 * n + 1) * (2 * n + 1)!)` on every iteration without using anything other than the sum from previous iterations. Assuming you will then get the correct answer, you can start to optimise it.

Comment: thank you Tau, i'm gonna apply your idea.

Comment: My `printf("%.20e\n", fen(2, 3, 1000));` reports `9.04287153380448766038e-03`. What is your result?

Comment: My result printf("%.4f\n",fen(2,3,1000)) = 0.0090.

Comment: (re. my suggestion above to remove optimization, it is problematic for `n = 1000` because the factorials become so large, but start with smaller `n` to verify.)

Comment: Afshin yep, I couble be over flow so I have to calculate one by one element to avoid overflow. And it works, but still results wrong output.

Comment: Thanks Arkku, Im gonna check with smaller n to verify my code.

Comment: @Afshin Well, my Win10 calculator is able to calculate 2001! and, yes, it's outside the representable range of a 64bit double, but note that OP's code is not calculating that value directly.

Comment: Are you sure about your results?I wrote a code and I get `0.162772` for `fen(2,3,1000)`. all answers are different, but I checked mine for few steps and I think mine should be ok.

Comment: Afshin: opps :((.Your result are the same as test case, maybe you are right. @@.
hmm, but i don't know where my code is wrong @@.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a small code to simplify things and here it is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double fen(double x,double y, int n) {
    double tmp = y;
    double sum = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        tmp *= -((x * y * (2*i-1)) / ((2*i) * (2*i+1) * (2*i+1)));
        sum += tmp;
    }

    return sum;
}

int main(void) {
    cout << fen(2,3,1) << endl;
    cout << fen(2,3,2) << endl;
    cout << fen(2,3,3) << endl;
    cout << fen(2,3,4) << endl;
    cout << fen(2,3,1000) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I only checked it till `fen(2,3,4)` and results were correct till there. it shows `0.162772` for `fen(2,3,1000)`:

```
1
0
0.18
0.161633
0.162772
```

**UPDATE:**

Updated code to use `cout` for output rather than `printf`. But I don't think this code really differs between `C` or `C++`.

In addition, remember that you reach quickly to limit of numerical precision of `double` in this code.

Comment: Also note that the limit of numerical precision of  `double` is reached way before n = 1000: https://ideone.com/AAwpUI

Comment: @Bob__ yea,...I wonder if `long double` still considered as higher precision or not.

Answer (score 0):

OP's formula mis-calculates the terms.

```
// int j=2,k=1;
int j=2,k=3;  // The loop's later calculation expect this to be initially 3

// in the loop
    // add
    a *= k;  // undo the prior terms /k

    for(;j<=i;j++) {
      // this part OK
    }

    // temp = a/(k*k);
    temp = a/k*;  // Only need /k
```

Other simplifications possible.